# How is it decided where 了 goes in 这时他得到了公众的支持?

Tags: grammar

In the Chinese wikipedia entry for Julius Caesar (the play), there is this sentence:

> 凯撒死后，布鲁塔斯进行演讲为自己辩护，这时他得到了公众的支持

Firstly, 进行演讲 means "to make a speech"/"to carry out a speech". Why is 了 not placed after the verb 进行? I suspect it is because the sentence is not finished and the tendency is to place 了 after the final verb in the sentence (in this case, 得到), but please tell me if I'm wrong.

Secondly, I don't understand when 了 is meant to come after the verb or at the end of the sentence. E.g. what is the difference between 这时他得到了公众的支持 and 这时他得到公众的支持了?

Comment: re 1stly: cf.＂实用现代汉语语法＂第３７３页：在一个叙述连续动作、事件的句子里，只要后面的分句中有动态助词＂了＂，前面的动态助词＂了＂一般都可以省去。（１）他站起来开门迎了出去。在这个句子里。＂了＂管辖＂站起来＂、＂开门＂和＂迎出去＂。（２）傍晚，我照样去替朱经理买小吃，照样买一块腐乳酱方送到了奶奶的床前。在这个句子里，＂了＂管辖＂照样去替朱经理买小吃＂、＂照样买一块腐乳酱方＂和＂送到了奶奶的床前＂。（３）最后，他退后一步，闪电般地联想了一下柳先生和母亲。（４）会上，他主动承担责任，取得了群众的谅解。i.e. grammar agrees with OP's conclusion
re 2ndly: difference between aspect (动态）了 and modal（语气）了 has been discussed countless times before at this site.

Comment: re 1stly continuing quoting from ＂实用现代汉语语法＂：上述句子的第一个分句的动词后可以加上动态助词＂了＂。例如：（１）＇他站了起来，开了门‌，​迎了出去。（２）＇傍晚，‌​我照样去替朱经理买了小吃，照样买了一块腐乳酱‌​方送到了奶奶的床前。３‌​）＇最后，他退了后一步，闪电般地联想了一下柳‌​先生和母亲。（４）＇会上，他主动承担了责任，‌​取得了群众的谅解。前边的句子里前几个动词后没有＂了＂，句子显得紧凑，语气急促；动词后都加上＂了＂时，增加了一些停顿，句子语气就变得舒缓了。（５）田汉不得不失望地脱下了刚刚穿上不到三个月的军装，考入了革命空气甚浓而又不收学费的长沙师范学校。田汉不得不失望地脱下刚刚穿上不到三个月的军装，考入了革命空气甚浓而又不收学费的长沙师范学校。（６）他苦笑了一下，轻轻地摇了摇头。他苦笑一下，轻轻地摇了摇头。并列动词作谓语，通常只在第二个动词后用动态助词＂了＂，也属于这种情况。例如：（１）大会讨论并通过了今年的生产计划。（２）通过这次互相访问，巩固并加强了两国人民的友谊。这种句子在第一个动词后也可以加上动态助词＂了＂，那样在第一个＂了＂之后就出现了一个明显的停顿：１）＇大会讨论了，并通过了今年的生产计划。（２）＇通过这次互相访问，巩固了，并加强了两国人民的友谊。

Comment: 句末有语气助词＂了＂时，如果没有特别的需要（参见下文＂两个＇了＇的连用＂），动态助词＂了＂一般都省去，这是因为语气助词＂‌​了＂管辖了前面的动词。例如：（１）A：你‌​在我们这儿吃点儿吧。B：不客气，我吃饭了‌​。（如果更强调＂吃＂已经发生，可以说：我‌​吃了饭了）（２）A：你怎么不敲门？里边有‌​人。B：刚才我敲门了，可是没有人答应。（‌​如果更强调＂敲＂已经发生，可以说：刚才我‌​敲了门了） 
（２）动词后结果补语或趋向补语，只要句子中有一个成分可以显示出动作状态已发生、已出现，句子中的＂了＂就可以省去。例如：（１）有一天，仿佛黑夜里亮起一道闪电，他突然想起了鲁迅先生。（２）放下电话，我的思想飞驰起来。仿佛又回到了南南出生时那战火纷飞的革命岁月。（３）最后他亲自把礼物送过去，又遭到了那个女孩子的拒绝。上述句子的＂了＂可以省去：（１）＇有一天，仿佛黑夜里亮起一道闪电，他突然想起鲁迅先生。这是因为＂有一天＂表示＂过去＂，一个过去有了结果的动作，当然已经发生了，所以表示动作发生的＂了＂可以省去。下面两个例子也一样：（２）＇放下电话，我的思想飞驰起来。仿佛又回到南南出生时那战火纷飞的革命岁月。（这个句子里显然表示过去 -- ＂那战火粉飞的岁月＂）（３）＇最后他亲自把礼物送过去，又遭到那个女孩子的拒绝。有时为了强调几个动作都已发生或完成，或在排比的句子里，

Comment: 也可以在每个动补短语或动词后都用＂了＂。例如：
（４）八十年代，由于实行改革开放政策，我们搞活了经济，打开了国门，扩大了外贸出口，提高了综合国力，也大大提高了人民的生活水平。（５）喜讯传到了北京，传到了祖国的每一个地方。关于补语后＂了＂的使用，参见第三编第五章第二节＂趋向补语＂。（３）主语为第三人称时，有时也可以省去动态助词＂了＂。例如：（１）昨天他给我一本书那本书很有用。（２）今天上课的时候张老师问我一个问题，我回答不上来，很丢人。（３）老师，他骂我。能这样省略动态助词＂了＂的用法很有限，第（１）、（２）两个例子都是双宾语词，而且有后续句；第（３）个例子是学生想老师告状。但是主语是第一、二人称时，一般不能这样用。

Comment: @user6065 Text without formatting is hard to read. Could you please make a separate answer instead of comments?

Answer (score 1):

My take on this is that, as you say, the aspectual 了 is placed after the final verb of the sentence, but I'm not aware of the existence of a hard rule for that. I would say it is mainly a matter of style. Maybe there are linguists here who can confirm this.

As for how to use 了 and where to position it in a sentence, this has been asked many times and you can find some pretty good and accepted answers here:
[Tense and use of 了](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/16/tense-and-use-of-%E4%BA%86)

> what is the difference between 这时他得到了公众的支持 and 这时他得到公众的支持了

The first one 这时他得到了公众的支持  is describing a completed action and sets the time in the past --> That time he obtained the support of the crowd.

The second one 这时他得到公众的支持了 describes a change of state (and tells nothing about time) --> This time he's got the support of the crowd. 
Which implies that he usually doesn't have it. 

However, since this last one example describes a change, the sentence with 得到 - which I perceive as a punctual event - plus the absence of a context sounds a bit weird to me.

So I'd prefer the first version any way.