# The absence of specifying when something happens in Chinese

Tags: grammar, time

I saw this example on another website:
他们都拿着票。

Tāmen dōu názhe piào.

They were all holding tickets.

I noticed that it said they *were* all holding tickets.
Does that imply it is the past tense?
Or is it a narrative?

If a sentence lacks a time indication is it always a certain way?
Should this sentence include 了？

Comment: I think it's a narrative, i.e. it depends on context. Without that, it should be progressive tense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chinese sometimes a sentense may lack a time, which is quite different from English, which has a specific tense. In this case the tense depends on the text and the language environment but not always means a same way.

For example, imagine that if you were buying a ticket and saw some people who hold tickets, "他们都拿着票" would mean progressive tense. If it is a narrative, it may means past tense.

As for "了"，"了" can be used in many tense.
See this [*Tense and use of 了*](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/16/tense-and-use-of-%E4%BA%86)

Comment: Yeah..there was no context, it was just an example, so thank you for clarifying.  I understand how to use 了, but my question was, can it still be indicative of past tense WITHOUT 了？

Comment: Of course. It's very flexible.

Comment: I will communicate with you at sometime through Google..I am busy studying right now..I don't like to break pace.  I love you btw

Comment: Great! I'm expecting! haha :)